# Using variables in following selections

Tags: jquery, var

For example, I have this code:

```
$('#div-ad-properties > div').hide();
```

Now I want to save outer div container into var, like this:

```
var divAdProps = $('#div-ad-properties');
```

How can I perform first code line using var instead of direct access to that div?
Is it possible to use vars like `$(divAdProps + ' > div').hide()`

Comment: Please explain what you want to do more clearly.

Comment: I mean how can i use variables in more complex selections, like first code line in my post.
Is it possible to use vars like $(divAdProps + ' > div').hide()

Comment: @ifeelgood `$('> div', divAdProps).hide()` is just what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var divAdProps = $('#div-ad-properties');
    divAdProp.find('> div').hide();
```

or a better one:

```
var divAdProps = $('#div-ad-properties');
    $('> div', divAdProp).hide();
  //-^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^---------this will find the direct child div nodes in 
  //passed selector context.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [.children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/)

```
var divAdProps = $('#div-ad-properties');
divAdProps.children('div').hide()
```

Comment: An alternative could be to use `divAdProps.find('div')`

Comment: @SidneyLiebrand could turn out to be costly as it will search the entire descendant tree instead of just the direct children as OP has used `#div-ad-properties > div` as the selector

Comment: You are right about that, the `>` sign will prevent that, so if I modify my first code it would become `divAdProps.find('> div')`. This will only look for direct children.